# Azure Functions "The operation has timed out." for timer trigger blob archival

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-triggers

I have a Python Azure Functions timer trigger that is run once a day and archives files from a general purpose v2 hot storage container to a general purpose v2 cold storage container. I'm using the Linux Consumption plan. The code looks like this:

```
container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=hot_conn_str, 
                                                   container_name=hot_container_name)
blob_list = container.list_blobs(name_starts_with = hot_data_dir)
files = []
for blob in blob_list:
    files.append(blob.name) 
for file in files:
    blob_from = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=hot_conn_str, 
                                             container_name=hot_container_name, 
                                             blob_name=file)
    data = blob_from.download_blob()
    blob_to = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=cold_conn_str, 
                                             container_name=cold_container_name, 
                                             blob_name=f'archive/{file}')
    try:                                         
        blob_to.upload_blob(data.readall())
    except ResourceExistsError:
        logging.debug(f'file already exists: {file}')
    except ResourceNotFoundError:
        logging.debug(f'file does not exist: {file}')
    container.delete_blob(blob=file)
```

This has been working for me for the past few months with no problems, but for the past two days I am seeing this error halfway through the archive process:
`The operation has timed out.`
There is no other meaningful error message other than that. If I manually call the function through the UI, it will successfully archive the rest of the files. The size of the blobs ranges from a few KB to about 5  MB and the timeout error seems to be happening on files that are 2-3MB. There is only one invocation running at a time so I don't think I'm exceeding the 1.5GB memory limit on the consumption plan (I've seen `python exited with code 137` from memory issues in the past). Why am I getting this error all of a sudden when it has been working flawlessly for months?
**Update**
I think  I'm going to try using the method found here for archival instead so I don't have to store the blob contents in memory in Python: https://www.europeclouds.com/blog/moving-files-between-storage-accounts-with-azure-functions-and-event-grid

Comment: How about set the function timeout?

Comment: Have you made any changes on your function configuration these days ?

Comment: The function timeout is set to 10 minutes already and the operation timeout happened after about 5 minutes. @Hury Shen, no I haven't made any configuration changes.

Comment: May I know if you added new functions(such as http trigger function or new timer trigger function) in the same function app recently ?

Comment: @Hury Shen, no new functions have been added

Comment: Can you see the error was caused by which line of your code ?

Comment: It looks like the error occurred on either one of the `BlobClient.from_connection_string()` calls or on `data = blob_from.download_blob()`. I did change the code to use `start_copy_from_url()` like the article I posted mentioned and it did work this morning and seems to be much faster.

Comment: It might have also failed on `blob_to.upload_blob(data.readall())` if the timeout happened before an exception was caught, but I'm suspecting it happened at `data = blob_from.download_blob()`

Comment: So does `start_copy_from_url()` solve all of your problems ?

Comment: It looks like `start_copy_from_url()` has been working, thanks! I also made a post on the Azure Q&A forums and an employee from Microsoft reached out to look into the `The operation has timed out.` issue

Comment: So could you please provide an answer under this post which summarize the workaround of `start_copy_from_url()` for other communities reference ?

Comment: Or do you mind if I summarize the workaround of `start_copy_from_url()` below as answer for other communities reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarize the solution from comments for other communities reference:

As mentioned in comments, OP uses [start_copy_from_url()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#start-copy-from-url-source-url--metadata-none--incremental-copy-false----kwargs-) method instead to implement the same requirements as a workaround.

`start_copy_from_url()` can process the file from original blob to target blob directly, it works much faster than using `data = blob_from.download_blob()` to store the file temporarily and then upload `data` to target blob.